How to fix mouse issues and clicking action in ubuntu 24.04 Noble

can i see why im not getting proper clicking actions from the mouse, like a program that shows input, output when buttons pushed?
is ubuntu 24 using older software for the mouse?
Is it a kernel problem causing the wireless mouse to not work properly.
Any fixes suggested would be great!


I have seen systemctl suspend clear up mouse issues such as unresponsiveness to key-down, key-up, etc.

Try the command line program xev.  It will show which button was pressed as well as showing any movement of the mouse.
